# python 3.5 tkinter text box recording

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a program that to record the input in a text box. After that, it would print it in a text
***Here is the code:***

```
from tkinter import*
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
a = Label(window, text="hi", font=('Helvetica', 32))
a.place(x=70, y = 80)
entry_box2=Entry(window,)
entry_box2.place(x=110, y=100)
def retrieve_input():
   input = entry_box2.get("1.0",'end-1c')
   a = Label(window, text= input, font=('Helvetica', 32))
   a.place(x=70, y = 80)
window.mainloop()
```

I hope I could get a response as fast as posiblle

Comment: `retrieve_input` is not used at all. When do you want it to be called?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. What is the problem, and what part of the solution do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `retrieve_input`. You can `bind()` it to `Entry` and execute when `Enter` is pressed.

```
entry_box2.bind('<Return>', retrieve_input)
```

And then you can add new `Label` or replace text in existing one.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def retrieve_input(event):
    # get text from Entry
    #txt = ent.get()
    txt = event.widget.get()

    # create new label with text
    l = tk.Label(root, text=txt)
    l.pack()

    # or change existing label
    lab['text'] = txt

    # clear entry
    #ent.delete(0, len(txt))
    event.widget.delete(0, len(txt))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

lab = tk.Label(root, text="Hello")
lab.pack()

ent = tk.Entry(root)
ent.pack()
ent.bind('<Return>', retrieve_input)

root.mainloop()
```